# Puppet agent should pick DNS and NTP servers based on location

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

We have 3 different Datacenters in our infrastructure. 
I am using puppetlabs/ntp module and saz/resolv_conf and using hiera_include('classes')  to install these 2 modules to all agents added to puppet.

Now my common.yaml file looks like this :

```
---
classes: ['ntp', 'resolv_conf']
ntp::servers:
        - datacenter1 NTP server
        - datacenter2 NTP server
        - datacenter3 NTP server
resolv_conf::nameservers:
        - datacenter1 DNS server
        - datacenter2 DNS server
        - datacenter3 DNS server
```

So my puppet agent in Datacenter 3 gets all 3 datacenters's NTP server and DNS server.

But i would like it to have just pick NTP server and DNS server based on its location.

Like if my puppet agent is in Datacenter 1 then, use NTP and DNS servers from Datacenter 1. 
How can i define that in my common.yaml ?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to change your hiera hierarchy e.g by defining [custom facts](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/3.0/custom_facts.html) on your puppet agents. So you define some custom fact, let say `data_center` and next you modify your hiera hierarchy e.g:

```
:hierarchy:
  - "%{::data_center}"
  - common
```

Value of `data_center` should depend on where your `agent` is located e.g  let assume that for agent in Datacenter N the value is `datacenter_n`. 
And finally, on puppet master create files `datacenter_n.yaml` with a content:

```
ntp::servers:
    - datacenterN NTP server
resolv_conf::nameservers:
    - datacenterN DNS server
```

Comment: Don't call it `my_custom_fact` though. How about `physical_location` or `data_center`?